# Factory_Girl array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

How to change the factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :slide do

    association :album
    description Faker::Name.name    
    photo { fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.join('spec/fixtures/sample_1.jpg'), 'image/jpeg') }

  end
end
```

to provide this (**photo is an array**):

```
{"slide"=>
  {"description"=>"Rylan Gerhold",
   "photo"=>
    [#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000005720510
      @content_type="image/jpeg",
      @headers=
       "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"slide[photo][]\"; filename=\"DSC_2382.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
      @original_filename="DSC_2382.JPG",
      @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20140328-1250-l4u0uv>>]},
```

rather than that:

```
{"slide"=>
  {"description"=>"Rylan Gerhold",
   "photo"=>
    #<Rack::Test::UploadedFile:0x0000000542b8a0
     @content_type="image/jpeg",
     @original_filename="sample_1.jpg",
     @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/sample_1.jpg20140328-32599-lwntv5>>},
 "album_id"=>"1",
 "controller"=>"slides",
 "action"=>"create"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :slide do

    association :album
    description Faker::Name.name    
    photo [Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/sample_1.jpg", "image/jpeg")]

  end
end
```

Comment: It's different approach for file upload but it doesn't solve the problem. I still got photo not as an array but: `"photo"=>
    #<Rack::Test::UploadedFile:0x000000040cd588`. I need it to test multipart/multiple upload form.

Comment: Much better! Quite funny as I tried to use [] with my code but I got syntax error. I have to accept your answer but at the same time I realized it didn't solve the real problem I faced. I would appreciate if you can check another question I asked with more details about it.

Comment: Glad to help :). Sure will check it.